# get_context_data method Django

Tags: django

```
# views.py
from django.views.generic import ListView
from books.models import Publisher

class PublisherList(ListView):
    model = Publisher
    context_object_name = 'my_favorite_publishers'

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['number'] = random.randrange(1, 100)
    return context
```

What does calling get_context_data with super() return?

What type of information?

And is the returned context from get_context_data given the contexT_object_name 'my_favorite_publishers'?

Comment: It returns the context that the `ListView` made. Here it thus contains a `'view'` that refers to the view, and `'my_favorite_publishers'` that maps to the queryset of `Publisher`s.

Answer (score 2):

The [**`.get_context_data(..)`** method [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/mixins-simple/#django.views.generic.base.ContextMixin.get_context_data) returns a dictionary that contains the context that will be passed to the template for rendering.

A [**`ListView`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#listview) will by default make a dictionary with the following keys and values:

- **`'view'`**: maps to the instance of this view;
- **`'paginator'`**: the paginator object if you paginate, `None` otherwise;
- **`'page_obj'`**: the page object of the current page if you paginate, `None` otherwise;
- **`'is_paginated'`**: `True` if you paginate, `False` otherwise;
- **`'object_list'`**: the (optionally) paginated queryset that is made by the `ListView`; and
- **`context_object_name`**: if you specified a `context_object_name` (or you have overwritten `get_context_object_name` and it does not return `None`, it will associate this with the (optionally) paginated queryset as well.

Comment: Im not quite understanding, context_object_name specifies a variable for a context, it is said in the documentation that context_object_name will be initialised in the context with value = object_list, is that correct and where does object_list come from?

Comment: @StreamlineAstra: from the implementation of `get_context_data` and other functions. For the implementation, see https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/2.2/django.views.generic.list/ListView/#get_context_data

Comment: Is the return value from get_query_set() passed into get_context_data() for object_list?

Comment: @StreamlineAstra: not directly, it is first passed through the `paginate_queryset` that optionally paginates it.

Answer (score 0):

```
       class EmployeeDetailView(DetailView):
             queryset=Employee.objects.all()
             template_name='testapp/detail.html'
             def get_context_data(self,**kwargs): 
                 context=super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
                 return context
```

In the above example,the class EmployeeDetailView is looking for an object(default context for DetailView) this object is provided by calling the method present in
parent class that is get_context_data this method accepts kwargs as parameter.

kwargs is a variable length argument list.the function get_context_data returns the context that contains object and this object would be sent to detail.html file,to display the data that the current objects holds(rendering process)